# hyperlink target = "_blank" not working for me in visual basic

Tags: html, vb.net

Here is my code...

```
    Dim link As New HyperLink
    link.Text = "Edit"
    link.Target = "_blank"
    link.NavigateUrl = "http://www.yahoo.com"
```

I'd like the page to open in a new tab when the link is clicked, I thought the link.target would do this, but it is not working for me. 
Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Can you also post the rendered HTML?

Comment: Yeah, sure. I forgot to put that in there...

Comment: Does it not work in any browser?

Comment: I advise against using the `target=""` attribute in general, but anyway, what *actually* happens when you click the link?

Comment: Seems to work fine. I assume you add it to the page with something like `Me.Controls.Add(link)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have posted is correct.

The issue is most likely that you have popup blockers turned on in your browser.

Comment: I didn't even think of that... Thank you :)